# jQuery mobile how to change select menu text align?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery and I am tiring to build a mobile web application, So I am using jquery mobile (1.4.5), and I have one simple problem I don't know how to change where the text in the select menu is located. I tried to do many things like to add a span with style of float:right or center and so on..

so here is my code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">                                          
                        <label for="select-custom-13">Select C</label>
                        <select style="text-align: right;" name="select-custom-13" id="select-custom-13" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-icon="false">
                          <span style="float:right; text-align:right;">
                          <option>עיר</option>
                            <option value="#">באר שבע</option>
                            <option value="#">ת"א</option>
                            <option value="#">אילת</option>
                            </span>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
```

and the out put is like this :

[image: This is how it looks right now]

And what I want it to look like is something like this :

[image]

So like you can see the text is on the right now and the cursor in the search field is also on the right.

Any advice how I can accomplish this ? Thanks is advance to everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Try dir="rtl" on a parent element.

```
<fieldset dir="rtl" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                        <label for="select-custom-11">Select A</label>                      
                        <select name="select-custom-11" id="select-custom-11"  data-native-menu="false" data-icon="false">
                           <option>מועדון</option>
                            <option value="#">פורום</option>
                            <option value="#">אבסנט</option>
                            <option value="#">זיגי</option>
                        </select>

                        <label for="select-custom-12">Select B</label>
                        <select name="select-custom-12" id="select-custom-12" data-role="date" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="false">
                            <option>תאריך</option>              
                                <option value="1">יום ראשון</option>
                                <option value="2">יום שני</option>
                               <option value="3">יום שלישי</option>
                               <option value="4">יום רבעי</option>                             
                        </select>
                        <label for="select-custom-13">Select C</label>
                        <select style="text-align: right;" name="select-custom-13" id="select-custom-13" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-icon="false">
                          <span style="float:right; text-align:right;">
                          <option>עיר</option>
                            <option value="#">באר שבע</option>
                            <option value="#">ת"א</option>
                            <option value="#">אילת</option>
                            </span>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle which appears to work with that edit. http://jsfiddle.net/x4hxbqam/